# One UIImage instance for multiple UIImageViews as backgrounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple UIImageViews in my application hierarchy and I need to set one UIImage for all of them with ability to change image for all UIImageViews at once. So I created UIImage as singleton pattern and then I set this image instance for each UIImageView. The problem is, that when a change the singleton image the UIImageViews are holding old image and not that newly assigned. You can image the situation like changing background for multiple views or screens and ability to change that background at once only by changing that UIImage instance. Why aren't UIImageViews updated? I don't know well about drawing images in UIImageView but I need to understand this behaviour. And I don't want to add new image to every screen and then changing all of them to achieve new "background effect". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want **all** the `UIImageView` in your application to apply the new background you can do something like `[[UIImageView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:yourImage]]`

(this is not a really proper solution as `UIImageView` usually should use its `image` property and not the `backgroundColor` one)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a method that updates all of your `UIImageView` instances at once. For example:

`- (void)updateImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self.imageViewA.image = image;
    self.imageViewB.image = image;
    self.imageViewC.image = image;
    self.imageViewD.image = image;
    self.imageViewE.image = image;
    self.imageViewF.image = image;
    self.imageViewG.image = image;
    self.imageViewH.image = image;
}`

If you are just creating a background pattern, I do suggest you follow Davide's method.

================

Edit: following on from the discussion in the comments, you could achieve this more succinctly using:

`- (void)updateImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    for (UIImageView *subview in self.viewArray) {
        subview.image = image;
    }
}`

Comment: This approach is what I want to avoid. You need to remember all UIImageView pointers... There must be something more elegant and clearer. Thanks

Comment: Well you could loop through your views subviews and update an `UIImageView` instances. Any particular reason you can't tile the image using a single `UIImageView`?

Comment: You just have to keep an `NSArray` keeping all the references and update the images in a simple loop.

Comment: ^ This is by far a safer method as the array would only contain objects YOU own.